# Tensorflow C++ API, a lot of time spent in tensorflow::GraphOptimizer::Optimize before first run

Tags: c++, performance, tensorflow

I have trained a tensorflow model, frozen it, and using it in C++ using the Tensorflow C++ API.
It works well, except that there is a long lag when call session->Run() for the first time.
By using GDB I can see that this time is spent in:   `tensorflow::GraphOptimizer::Optimize`.
My application is supposed to be relatively short and this adds a non negligible amount of time to the total runtime, so I'm looking a way to do this optimisation in advance (or disable it maybe).

Comment: Are you creating your graph in C++ directly or is it exported from Python as a `GraphDef`?

Comment: I load it as: `tensorflow::GraphDef` with `tensorflow::ReadBinaryProto`

Comment: How are you exporting the graph from Python? Maybe you can prune it further to remove the parts that you don't need, which _maybe_ makes that graph optimization faster?

Comment: I'm using `convert_variables_to_constants` from `graph_util`, this keeps only the nodes used for the outputs I specify.

Comment: Mmm yes that should be the case... About what amount of lag are you experiencing anyway? I mean compared to the usual running time of the model. I have also experienced lags in the first run (I think it even happens in Python when you create a session), but not large enough to be a disturbance...

Comment: It's maybe 5-10 seconds, for a computation that is a few seconds long.

Comment: Okay then I guess it's the same that I got, only my model runs in a few milliseconds and the first run is, I don't know, maybe one second? (which is a lot of difference, but in my case the model runs constantly for a very long time so it doesn't matter). Looks like the lag scales with the complexity of the model... I don't know if there is any way to avoid it, but it seems like it's a "normal" thing (as in, not a specific problem with your model).